# Setting resolution for a specific tab in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I want to test an iPhone skin for a site. To do this, I want my Chrome to act as if its screen resolution is the same as an iPhone; also, it will be best if this would only effect one tab and the other tabs in Chrome would act normally. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ScreenFly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) to test your website on the iPhone resultion (screenfly uses a iframe with a specified width and height).

If you want to resize Chrome there are many extensions, some of them:

- [Resolution Test](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal)
- [Resolution Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cfpobndlielepmhenppdhjgpjkdkokmi)